# Which diagram is suitable for a dataset with large range?

Tags: histogram, diagram

I have a list of records that have large distance for example:

```
column1    column2 
---------  --------
dataset1   1215000 
dataset2   15 
dataset3   1500
dataset4   684500
dataset5   1666
```

As the range of data is too large, if I show the data in a histogram in e.g., excel I loose some of rows due to their small numbers. I want to illustrate all of rows in one diagram so that I can show all (like a histogram). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a log scale?  A quick google search shows this page as a way to do that in Excel:  http://tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/flexible_log_scale/help.html